# Date and time range where Date() and Date()-1 can't be use in access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set up a query that pulls data from a date field. The date range (for example) that I need is from 3:40 PM of yesterday to today's date up to 3:40 PM. In other words my day does not star at midnight, so the function Date() can't cover it.

I have set up the query as follows:

Between #2/5/2018 3:40:00 PM# And #2/6/2018 3:39:59 PM#

in a field formatted for general Date (mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM or PM). With this I would have to change the query every day.

I would like to be able to use the function Date() & Date()-1 to replace today's date (Date()) and Yesterday (Date()-1). How can I do it?

I have also tried having two fields one for the Date (formatted as short date mm/dd/yyyy) when the order was entered, and the time the order was entered (formatted for general Date (mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM or PM). However when I use the function Date() on the date field and >#h:mm:ss# on the Time field the query yields 0 records.

Comment: Do you want to enter the time or do you need 24 hours from the current time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple calculus with dates and times. Try the following:

```
Between Date() - 1  + #3:40:00 PM#  And  Date() + #3:39:59 PM#
```